# Pass sender of programmatically called segue to destination

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

Sorry if the title isn't very clear, but hopefully I can elaborate here.

I have a ViewController `MatchLineupViewController`, which displays 22 buttons to represent rugby players on a team.  When the user taps any of these buttons, a modal segue is called programmatically in the following method:

```
- (IBAction) showSquadSelector:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SeguePopupSquad" sender:sender];
}
```

The modal ViewController which is then displayed is called `SquadSelectViewController`.  It passes back a selected player object to the `MatchLineupViewController`, which is acting as a delegate.  This works perfectly.

However, I want to assign the `profile_picture` attribute of the returned object to the `UIButton` that sent the segue in the first place.

**EDIT -** The returned object is an NSDictionary as shown in the following code:

```
- (void) selectPlayer:(NSDictionary *)player forButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [sender.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[player objectForKey:@"profile_picture"]]];
}
```

How would I go about doing this?   If you require any further code to understand what I am asking, I can provide it.

Many thanks,
Chris

**EDIT -**

```
- (IBAction) showSquadSelector:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SeguePopupSquad" sender:sender];
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SeguePopupSquad"]) {
        SquadSelectViewController *ssvc = (SquadSelectViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        ssvc.myDelegate = self;
        ssvc.senderButton = sender;
    }
}

- (void) selectPlayer:(NSDictionary *)player forButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [sender.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[player objectForKey:@"profile_picture"]]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [player description]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [sender description]);
}
```

Comment: "of the returned object" - what's the returned object?

Comment: The returned object is an NSDictionary of player data, such as name, profile picture and database ID.  It is sent from the "child" ViewController back to the "parent" ViewController through the use of Delegates.

- (void) selectPlayer:(NSDictionary *)player {
    //work with returned NSDictionary
}

Comment: Then, in the delegate method: `dictionary[@"profile_picture"] = theButton;`, is it that?

Comment: The problem is determining the button that started the process in the first place, as all 22 buttons call the same `showSquadSelector` method.

Comment: Ah, I see. However, Dasblinkenlight seems to just have answered your question.

Comment: Updated code above to show my attempt at implementing dasblinkenlight's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward the `sender` of your `showSquadSelector:` method to the segue, like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SeguePopupSquad" sender:sender];
```

The `sender` of the segue would be the button that triggered the segue, so the code triggered from the segue would know what button has triggered it: your `prepareForSegue:` would have the correct `UIButton`. You can now add it to the returned dictionary at a predetermined key (say, `@"senderButton"`) and examine it upon the return from the segue.

Comment: I've tried this, and posted updated code in my question.  It doesn't seem to work.  I'm guessing I'm passing the button incorrectly somewhere?

Comment: Check with logging if you still have a button, but note that you usually set a button's image with `setImage:forControlState:` - assigning it directly to the image view might not let the button rearrange its subviews to display it.

Comment: @ChrisMatthews, outlets in the destination view controller are not set at the time of prepareForSegue, so doing ssvc.senderButton = sender won't work (senderButton will be nil).

Comment: Got it working, the problem was I was trying to use the `sender.imageView setImage` method instead of the `sender setImage:forControlState`.